# Can't create a fresh Nuxt project?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, create-nuxt-app

I tried to create a fresh Nuxt.js project with the below command. Everything has worked fine previously except today.

The process as well as the output are all described below.

Anyone could help me to investigate this ?

```
begueradj@FA512:~$ yarn create nuxt-app client
yarn create v1.22.5
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...

success Installed "create-nuxt-app@3.7.1" with binaries:
      - create-nuxt-app

create-nuxt-app v3.7.1
✨  Generating Nuxt.js project in client
? Project name: client
? Programming language: JavaScript
? Package manager: Yarn
? UI framework: Vuetify.js
? Nuxt.js modules: Axios - Promise based HTTP client
? Linting tools: ESLint
? Testing framework: Jest
? Rendering mode: Universal (SSR / SSG)
? Deployment target: Server (Node.js hosting)
? Development tools: jsconfig.json (Recommended for VS Code if you're not using typescript)
? Continuous integration: None
? Version control system: Git
warning nuxt > @nuxt/babel-preset-app > core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the
 number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even i
f nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
warning nuxt > @nuxt/webpack > webpack-hot-middleware > querystring@0.2.1: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should 
use the URLSearchParams API instead.
warning nuxt > @nuxt/webpack > webpack > node-libs-browser > url > querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new c
ode should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
warning nuxt > @nuxt/webpack > webpack > watchpack > watchpack-chokidar2 > chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrad
e to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
warning nuxt > @nuxt/webpack > webpack > watchpack > watchpack-chokidar2 > chokidar > fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node 
v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
warning nuxt > @nuxt/webpack > webpack > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lyd
ell/urix#deprecated
warning nuxt > @nuxt/webpack > webpack > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/
resolve-url#deprecated
warning vue-jest > extract-from-css > css > urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
warning vue-jest > babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs > babel-runtime > core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintai
ned and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versi
ons could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-
js.
error babel-jest@27.0.6: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^10.13.0 || ^12.13.0 || ^14.15.0 || >=
15.0.0". Got "14.4.0"
error Found incompatible module.

yarn install v1.22.5
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@2.3.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.3.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.

/home/begueradj/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/sao/lib/installPackages.js:108
        throw new SAOError(`Failed to install ${packageName} in ${cwd}`)
        ^

SAOError: Failed to install packages in /home/begueradj/client
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/begueradj/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/sao/lib/installPackages.js:108:15)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1051:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:287:5) {
  __sao: true
}
error Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: /home/begueradj/.yarn/bin/create-nuxt-app
Arguments: client
Directory: /home/begueradj
Output:

info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/create for documentation about this command.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message shows the problem:

```
error babel-jest@27.0.6: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module.
Expected version "^10.13.0 || ^12.13.0 || ^14.15.0 || >= 15.0.0". Got "14.4.0"
                                                                        
error Found incompatible module.
```

`create-nuxt-app`'s `babel-jest` dependency was recently updated to require Node `14.15.0` or newer, but it looks like you're still using `14.4.0`.

Update your Node version to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`npx create-nuxt-app <my-project>` is still the fastest and easiest way to get a brand new Nuxt project. Not sure if you'll get the Node issue with it.

For more details, check this one: https://github.com/nuxt/create-nuxt-app